How am I suppose to update the Ionic components CSS?
I'm updating an app with Ionic v3 and Angular v5 to Ionic v6 and Angular v13, but I'm having a lot of headache with css.
In v3 theming docs, it says:

However, this classes do not exist in v6 and I found nothing in the docs about this change. I also looked in the breaking changes to Ionic v4 (which has a lot of change) but I didn't find anything regarding this.
Also, there are a lot of styles for Ionic components (ion-input, ion-select, etc) in the ionic-angular npm package (for v3) that are not present in the @ionic/angular package (for v6).

you are better off just copying/pasting code over into a brand new project to avoid this headache.

@StackoverBlows but won't I have the same problem? If the classes don't exist in the new version, the CSS will continue to break. Unless you are saying to copy the CSS rules in the npm packages, but I don't know if this is safe to do.

Yes. Look for yourself here are the ionic docs and follow the migration guides. you got a long way to for from v4-v8. goodluck! - https://ionicframework.com/docs/updating/4-0
